# Erro: could not devise a query plan for the given query

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Whats wrong with this query?I'm trying to run on redshift but i'm getting the erro `could not devise a query plan for the given query` .

The 2 tables have filenames and I wish to discover which files they share and which they dont(I need to know which one has the file in this case).
In case they share, the filename would appear on both columns, in case they dont share, the filename would appear only on the column of the table that has it while the other column would be null/empty. There are rows with the same filename so thats why I used distinct. I used substring to ignore the extension.

```
select distinct a.filename as arquivo_a , r.filename as arquivo_r 
from table1 a
FULL JOIN table2 r ON  SUBSTRING(a.filename,1,LEN(a.filename) - 4) = SUBSTRING(r.filename,1,LEN(r.filename) - 4)
```

Comment: If you do an INNER JOIN do you get the same error? Are all records returned from both tables?

Comment: I dont get the same erro with inner join, I used full join because i wanted all records from both even the ones they dont share, while knowing whcih one had it.

Comment: There might be multiple reasons for this. Since I don't know how your tables are designed and their respective datatype, I would suggest you to go through the threads: (i) https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/334.1081278333@sss.pgh.pa.us and (ii) https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/05d801c41bd8$daf4f8f0$0403a8c0@fejleszt4

Comment: Nevermind, I just discovered its because filename is not unique, so i needed `ON a.id = r.id` instead of using the filename.

Answer (score 2):

You got this error because you can't use formula on the left join field, so you should have used at least something like:

```
select *
from table1 a
FULL JOIN table2 r 
   ON a.filename_without_ext = SUBSTRING(r.filename,1,LEN(r.filename) - 4)
```

and it would have worked.

The fact that the filename was not unique is not relevant